# Convert text into symbols, then convert symbols into sound

Tags: android, android-widget, morse-code

I'd like to know how to let a user input text ex. "TEXT", then have my app convert that "TEXT" into something like "@&^@", then have my app recognize "@&^@" as 4 different letters, ex. "@" "&" "^" "@", then play that letter's sound. I have recordings of each letter's sound.

ANY help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Think of it like making Morse Code

Comment: But why convert it in the first place instead of just playing the sounds for each letter?

Comment: @Gabriel Neguţ, that's a good point.  I think I want the experience of creating the extra step. I agree that it may not be the fastest or the most efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, create an app with an EditText.
2. Then create a listener which detects when a user has changed the text.
3. In that listener....

   - retrieve the text
   - Convert it into your symbols
   - For each symbol, play the appropriate sound. You'll need to implement something that queues them in order, so one starts playing once the last has finished.

I suggest you tackle these one step at a time, asking one question on this site for each of the above points.